# Adobe Analytics 2.0 API endpoint to get report suite events, props, and evars

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

I'm having a hard time finding a way in the 2.0 API that I can get a list of Evars, Props and Events for a given report suite. The 1.4 version has the [reportSuite.getEvents()](https://github.com/AdobeDocs/analytics-1.4-apis/blob/master/docs/admin-api/methods/report_suite/r_GetEvents.md) endpoint and similar for Evars and Props.

Please let me know if there is a way to get the same data using the 2.0 API endpoints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [API v2.0](https://github.com/AdobeDocs/analytics-2.0-apis) github docs aren't terribly useful, but the [Swagger UI](https://adobedocs.github.io/analytics-2.0-apis/#/) is a bit more helpful, showing endpoints and parameters you can push to them, and you can interact with it (logging in with your oauth creds) and see requests/responses.

The two API endpoints in particular you want are `metrics` and `dimensions`. There are a number of options you can specify, but to just get a dump of them all, the full endpoint URL for those would be:

`https://analytics.adobe.io/api/[client id]/[endpoint]?rsid=[report suite id]`

**Where:**

**`[client id]`** - The client id for your company. This *should* be the same value as the legacy `username:companyid` (the `companyid` part) from v1.3/v1.4 API shared secret credentials, with the exception that it is suffixed with "0", e.g. if your old `username:companyid` was "crayonviolent:foocompany", the `[client id]` would be "foocompany0", because..reasons? I'm not sure what that's about, but it is what it is.

**`[endpoint]`** - Value should be "metrics" to get the events, and `dimensions` to get the props and eVars. So you will need to make 2 API endpoint requests.

**`[rsid]`** - The report suite id you want to get the list of events/props/eVars from.

**Example:**

`https://analytics.adobe.io/api/foocompany0/metrics?rsid=fooglobal`

One thing to note about the responses: they aren't like the v1.3 or v1.4 methods where you query for a list of only those specific things. It will return a json array of objects for every single event and dimension respectively, even the native ones, calculated metrics, classifications for a given dimension, etc. AFAIK there is no baked in way to filter the API query (that's in any documentation I can find, anyways..), so you will have to loop through the array and select the relevant ones yourself.

I don't know what language you are using, but here is a javascript example for what I basically do:

```
var i, l, v, data = { prop:[], evar: [], events:[] };

// dimensionsList - the JSON object returned from dimensions API call
// for each dimension in the list..
for (i=0,l=dimensionsList.length;i<l;i++) {
  // The .id property shows the dimension id to eval
  if ( dimensionsList[i].id ) {
    // the ones we care about are e.g. "variables/prop1" or "variables/evar1"
    // note that if you have classifications on a prop or eVar, there are entries 
    // that look like e.g. "variables/prop1.1" so regex is written to ignore those
    v = (''+dimensionsList[i].id).match(/^variables\/(prop|evar)[0-9]+$/);
    // if id matches what we're looking for, push it to our data.prop or data.evar array
    v && v[1] && data[v[1]].push(dimensionsList[i]);
  }
}
// metricsList - the JSON object returned from metrics API call
// basically same song and dance as above, but for events. 
for (var i=0,l=metricsList.length;i<l;i++) {
  if ( metricsList[i].id ) {
    // events ids look like e.g. "metrics/event1"
    var v = (''+metricsList[i].id).match(/^metrics\/event[0-9]+$/);
    v && data.events.push(metricsList[i]);
  }
}
```

And then the result `data` object will have `data.prop`,`data.evar`, and `data.events`, each an array of the respective props/evars/events.

**Example object entry for an `data.events[n]`:**

```
{
    "id": "metrics/event1",
    "title": "(e1) Some event",
    "name": "(e1) Some event",
    "type": "int",
    "extraTitleInfo": "event1",
    "category": "Conversion",
    "support": ["oberon", "dataWarehouse"],
    "allocation": true,
    "precision": 0,
    "calculated": false,
    "segmentable": true,
    "supportsDataGovernance": true,
    "polarity": "positive"
}
```

**Example object entry for an `data.evar[n]`:**

```
{
    "id": "variables/evar1",
    "title": "(v1) Some eVar",
    "name": "(v1) Some eVar",
    "type": "string",
    "category": "Conversion",
    "support": ["oberon", "dataWarehouse"],
    "pathable": false,
    "extraTitleInfo": "evar1",
    "segmentable": true,
    "reportable": ["oberon"],
    "supportsDataGovernance": true
}
```

**Example object entry for a `data.prop[n]`:**

```
{
    "id": "variables/prop1",
    "title": "(c1) Some prop",
    "name": "(c1) Some prop",
    "type": "string",
    "category": "Content",
    "support": ["oberon", "dataWarehouse"],
    "pathable": true,
    "extraTitleInfo": "prop1",
    "segmentable": true,
    "reportable": ["oberon"],
    "supportsDataGovernance": true
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is what I was looking for. Definitely not quite as straightforward as I had hoped, but it get's what I need. The app is a JS app so your sample code is perfect for me. Again, thanks for the detailed response.

Comment: @Crayon Violent thanks for your observation however I see these metrics are metadata of reports. how do i fetch the values for this field? for example metrics is metrics/event1 what is the value for this field?

Comment: @Jmh2013 please check this

Comment: @atultripathi are you asking how to get the values of a given dimension or metric, e.g. the values of "metrics/event1" for a given date range etc.? If so.. then please see the Swagger UI link I posted in answer. It shows all of the endpoints and models for them.  For example,  the top level `/metrics` endpoint will return a list of all of the available metrics with their general config info.  Whereas endpoint `/metrics/event1` will give you the actual data for the `event1` reports