# Is there a way to export the enabled Conversion Variables, Traffic Variables and Success events to excel in Adobe Analytics?

Tags: adobe-analytics

I wanted to export the list of variables defined in Adobe Analytics, to create a document. But then other than copy paste i don't see any other way to do the same. I have to do the same for more than 70 Report suits. I feel its too much manual work.

I have tried copy paste. Which i don't want to do, as its too much manual work.

Is there a way which i am missing in Adobe Analytics which does this easily in one click or something? As in <strike>Google Analytics</strike> Google Tag Manager we have an option to export the container which i don't see in Adobe Analytics.

Comment: You can write a script making use of the Adobe API. See this post for relevant info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58443424/adobe-analytics-2-0-api-endpoint-to-get-report-suite-events-props-and-evars

Comment: BTW I don't think GA has option to export enabled dimension/metric info from the GA admin interface? I think maybe you are talking about the Google Tag Manager container export, which is not the same thing.

Comment: @CrayonViolent Yes, my bad i was speaking about the GTM.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @CrayonViolent. But i found one more way to get the list of variables defined.

The admin Report Suite Manager lets you to do the same.

Analytics > Admin > Report Suites

- Select Report Suite
- Click on Download:

[image: Screenshot Download]

This will Generates an Excel spreadsheet of all settings for the currently selected report suites.

I hope this helps.

Comment: +1 hey that's cool! wonder how long that's been around? But.. eww, it's just a tab delimited dump of everything with no dedicated columns, etc. I think I'll stick to pulling from the API since the data is a lot easier to parse!

Comment: Yes @CrayonViolent it is tab delimited. But we can just convert it to .xlsx and with the help of Data tool in excel (Text to  Columns) we can easily format and get the required data.

Answer (score 0):

Both the API and export options are great.

Another option is to use ObservePoint's free Google Sheets add-on to pull all props, eVars, listVars, processing rules, etc. into a spreadsheet. I believe it's limited to one report suite at a time, but I use it regularly to generate sharable and editable SDRs. (The add-on supports making updates in the spreadsheet and pushing them back up to Adobe Analytics.)

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/observepoint-labs/ohpgoaikjjdkfjalakolccdibikodoeo?hl=en